# which <li> element was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 (maybe more) li elements.

```
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
 <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get which elements was clicked(***which row??***). If random user clicks  **Two** I want to get `$("li:eq(1)")`(as typed).

How can I get this result?

Comment: Dear @Programmer I need samething in javascript not in jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.index`. Something like this:

```
$('ul > li').click(function() {
   alert($(this).index($(this).parent('li'));
});
```

Comment: @Programmer: keep in mind that this will only make sense if you have a fixed order of lines. Also, in a real situation you will probably want to change `ul > li`, in favour of `#idoftheul li`

Comment: Dear @blockhead I need same thing in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ulId li").click(function() {
   $(this).something(); //the clicked li is $(this), and you can invoke functions on it.
})
```

Comment: @Programmer this was an example. $(this) gives you the object, and you can call any existing function on it

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text node value of the clicked item with:

```
$('li').click(function(){
   var clicked = $(this).text();

  alert(clicked+" was clicked");
});
```

Comment: Dear @Ben I need same thing in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tbugV/1/

```
$("#mylist li").each(function(index)
                     {
                         $(this).data("row", index);
                     }).
                click(function() 
                      {
                        alert($(this).data("row"));   
                      });
```

Comment: I don't want to get clicked element's text. I want to get which row?

Answer (score 1):

If you give your elements an id such as

```
<ul id="mylist">
 <li id="el_1">One</li>
 <li id="el_2">Two</li>
 <li id="el_3">Three</li>
 <li id="el_4">Four</li>
 <li id="el_5">Five</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use `$(this).attr(id)` in the `click` handler to determine the id of the clicked element. This will also allow to give non sequential ids to your elements, and will detach what's written in the `<li>` from the actual value you get.
Also, you can encode multiple value in the id (for instance `el_5_3`) which can be useful sometimes.

```
$("#mylist li").click(function()
                      {
                      var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
                      alert("You clicked the element with id="+id[1]);    
                      });
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jFrdp/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('html').click(function() {
     var el = e.target;    
     alert(el);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As people just keep posting code, and no explanations, I will try the other way around...

The click event handler is called in the scope of the clicked element, so you can use the `this` keyword to access the element. You can use `$(this)` to get a jQuery object that contains the clicked element, so that you can use jQuery methods on it.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('ul li').click(function({
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert('You clicked on the item with the text "' + text + '"');
  }));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function(){
alert($(this).html());
});
```

This code will alert one when user will click the one button.